# This mergesort should "of" failed, right?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, keyword, mergesort

I noticed something weird while reviewing [this mergesort implementation on Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92020/9357)…

```js
/************************************************************
 * Mergesort implementation
 ***********************************************************/

function sort(array) {
  var len = array.length;
  var middle = Math.floor(len*0.5);
  var left = array.slice(0,middle);
  var right = array.slice(middle, len);

  if (len == 1) {
    return array;
  } else {

  }

  return merge(sort(left), sort(right));
}


function merge(left, right) {
  var a = left.length;
  var b = right.length;


  if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
    if (left[0] > right[0]) {
      return [].concat(left[0], merge(left.slice(1,a), right));
    } else {
      return [].concat(right[0], merge(right.slice(1,b), left));
    }
  } else if (a == 0) {
    return right;
  } else of (b == 0)
    return left;

}


/************************************************************
 * Demonstration
 ***********************************************************/

function doSort() {
    var array = document.getElementById('in').value.split(/[, ]+/).map(function(e) {
        return parseInt(e);
    });
    var sorted = sort(array);
    document.getElementById('out').value = sorted;
}

function generateRandom(len) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        array.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
    }
    document.getElementById('in').value = array;
};

generateRandom(20);
```

```html
<button onclick="generateRandom(20)">⬇︎ Generate random numbers ⬇︎</button>
<div><input id="in" size="80"></div>
<button onclick="doSort()">⬇︎ Sort ⬇︎</button>
<div><input id="out" size="80" disabled></div>
```

The last conditional branch is **`else of`** rather than `else if`.  Normally, `else of` should result in a syntax error.  Yet, no matter how hard I try, I can't trigger the syntax error — it always successfully returns an array sorted in descending order!

I know, `else of (b == 0)` could just be replaced by `else`, but still, I want to know: How could this code possibly work?

Comment: The code doesent work for me.

Comment: works just fine on chromium...

Answer (score 4):

This works because of a combination of 2 "bad things" about Javascript: skipping braces in block statements that contain only a single statement, and [semicolon insertion](http://cjihrig.com/blog/the-dangers-of-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/).

Your `if` statement, properly braced, should look like this:

```
if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
    if (left[0] > right[0]) {
        return [].concat(left[0], merge(left.slice(1,a), right));
    } else {
        return [].concat(right[0], merge(right.slice(1,b), left));
    }
} else if (a == 0) {
    return right;
} else of (b == 0) {
    return left;
}
```

but, because of the missing braces and semicolon insertion, Javascript is seeing/parsing it like this:

```
if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
    if (left[0] > right[0]) {
        return [].concat(left[0], merge(left.slice(1,a), right));
    } else {
        return [].concat(right[0], merge(right.slice(1,b), left));
    }
} else if (a == 0) {
    return right;
} else {
    of(b == 0);
}

return left;
```

If you always pass in legitimate `left` and `right` arrays then this last `else` branch is never reached, hence why you haven't seen an exception.

If you pass in an empty `right` array, it will reach the last branch and throw `of is not a function`:

```
merge([10, 20, 30], []);
```

Any respectable coding standard should explicitly require these 2 "features" of Javascript never be used... but that's just one opinion.

Comment: Wouldn't the `else of` part equal `else { of (b == 0) } return left;` ?

Comment: If anything, it would be `else ( of (b == 0) ) { return left; }`

Comment: `else` doesn't take "arguments".. but parentheses do more than just define lists of arguments in Javascript.

Comment: I'm skeptical. There is no `for` loop in the function. If I just try to evaluate `of (b == 0)`, I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: of`. If I define a function named `of`, then it treats `of (b == 0)` as a function call.

Comment: @200_success yeah its a *really* interesting one.. I've found that it consistently generates an error *IF* the branch in question is actually reached, but fails to generate an error otherwise.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan If `else` is not followed by `{`, only the next statement is put inside that else block. And as far as I can see, the next statement is `of (b == 0)` (using line break as statement separator), which, in ES5, is parsed as a function call to `of()` (which likely doesn't exist). Then the `else` block ends, and then comes the return.

Comment: @200_success updated with a better example of what's going on

Answer (score 3):

`of` is a keyword in ES6, used for iterating over objects..
but in this case the `of` is behaving as function not keyword..

The function code never goes to `else of (b == 0) return left;` part.. so compiler is not throw `ReferenceError: of is not defined`

if you will change `of` keyword into another word like `else often(b==0)....` then also code work

when you send right side empty then code will throw error `ReferenceError: of is not defined`, so finally this is only typo.